# sbt can't find local repository defined by Resolver.file()

Tags: scala, sbt

I use

```
name := "sbt-publish-test"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("sbt-repo",  file("/home/pishen/sbt-repo")))
```

and `sbt publish` to publish my project into the directory.

Now in another project, I want to resolve the project I just published. I use

```
resolvers += "my-repo" at "file:///home/pishen/sbt-repo"

libraryDependencies += "default" %% "sbt-publish-test" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

and is able to resolve the project without any error. The result of `show resolvers` is:

```
> show resolvers 
[info] List(my-repo: file:///home/pishen/sbt-repo)
```

But, when I use

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("my-repo", file("/home/pishen/sbt-repo"))

libraryDependencies += "default" %% "sbt-publish-test" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

The result of `show resolvers` become:

```
> show resolvers
[info] List(FileRepository(my-repo,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(), artifactPatterns=List(/home/pishen/sbt-repo/[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=true, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)))
```

and sbt said that it can't resolve the dependency when I typed `sbt update`:

```
[warn]  module not found: default#sbt-publish-test_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/pishen/.ivy2/local/default/sbt-publish-test_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/default/sbt-publish-test_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/sbt-publish-test_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== my-repo: tried
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: default#sbt-publish-test_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Is this a bug? Or am I use `Resolver.file()` in a wrong way? What's the difference between `"name" at "url"` and `Resolver.file()`? I'm using sbt 0.13.7.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1917

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that when you use `Resolver.file` in that context, it's intended to be more of a "builder" creator, expecting subsequent method calls to fill in additional configuration information that have different defaults when using the `"name" at "uri"` syntax.

The [sbt ScalaDoc for `Resolver.file.apply`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.Resolver$$file$) alludes to something along these lines:

> Constructs a file resolver with the given name. The patterns to use must be explicitly specified using the `ivys` or `artifacts` methods on the constructed resolver object.

When I've done something similar to what you're doing, I start with a `File` and use its API to convert it into the URI form:

```
resolvers += "my-repo" at file("/home/pishen/sbt-repo").toURI.toASCIIString
```